# How can I validate this sequence F(x)=F(x+y)+F(x-z) to be used in my function?

Tags: javascript, sequence, fibonacci

I am writing a program that makes use of the Fibonacci sequence: *F(n)= F(n-1) + F(n-2)*. The program will take in a user's input which will be a number and output the sequence $F(x)$. As an additional task, I have been asked to accept two additional inputs from the user **y and z** where *F(x)= F(x-y) + F(x-z)* and output the sequence of numbers. If a number does not exist in the sequence output a 1 instead. The Fibonacci sequence seems to be working fine, but I am not sure if I have the *F(x)=F(x+y)+F(x-z)* sequence correct. Below is a code snippet of the function that handles both sequences:

```js
function fibonacci(x, y, z) {
    let fibos = [];
    fibos[0] = 1;
    fibos[1] = 1;
    fibos[2] = 2;
    if (y !== '' && z !== '') {
      for (let i = 3; i < x; i++){
        fibos[i] = fibos[x -y] + fibos[x - z]
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 3; i < x; i++){
        fibos[i] = fibos[i -1] + fibos[i -2]
      }
    }
    return fibos;
}
```

The function above, takes in three arguments **x,y,z**. If y and z are not initialized the function will use the second sequence which is the fibonacci, however, if they are initialized it uses the function under question which again is *F(x)=F(x+y)+F(x-z)*. So my question is do I have the function programmatically correct and how would I understand this mathematically?

Comment: Fix the parts where you expose the funcion F(x+y). I think you it should be F(x - y).

Answer (score 0):

`F(x)= F(x-y) + F(x-z)` must be represented as below:

```
function fibonacci(x, y, z) {
  let sequence = [0]; // f(0) = 0
  let v1,             // f(x-y)
      v2;             // f(x-z)
  
  for (let i=1; i < x; i++) {
    // f(x - y)
    v1 = sequence[i - y];
    // f(x-z)
    v2 = sequence[i - z];
    
    // If a number does not exist in the sequence output a 1 instead
    if (typeof v1 === 'undefined')
      v1 = 1;
    if (typeof v2 === 'undefined')
      v2 = 1;

    sequence.push(v1 + v2)
  }
  
  return sequence
}
```

this will work for Fibonacci `F(x) = f(x-1) - f(x-2)` too